# Preventing user creation, but allowing edit

Tags: 7, users

I have defined a role in which I'd like to grant:

1) Permission to edit users

2) Prevent from creating new users

Is this possible? I only see one permission under User called "Administer users" which looks like grants both abilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the [Administer Users By Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module. The 7.0-2.x version depends on the [Chain Menu Access API](https://www.drupal.org/project/chain_menu_access).

After both modules have been installed and enabled, you will be able to grant user edit but not user add permissions to certain roles within the /admin/people/permissions form.

Nice side-effect: The user editors won't be able to alter the site admin's profile, if you don't allow it, as it could cause serious problems.

Comment: Is there a workaround to achieve this in a custom module and not use those modules?

Comment: I remember having seen you asking another question the same time as the above one, regarding checking additional user permissions in a hook_form_alter(). Found that this approach - well done - would be a reasonable alternative. May I ask why you don't like to use the above modules?